# "Those who" vs "Them who"

Tags: english, grammar

I have asked this question in [ELL site](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/28876/those-who-vs-them-who), but as I haven't received any answer from grammatical point of view, I am asking the same question here. Please help.

> I pity those who lost their money in gambling.
>
> I pity them who lost their money on gambling.

I know the first one is correct, but I think there is nothing wrong grammatically with the second sentence, as both **them** and **those** are pronoun. Am I wrong somewhere? Please help me.

Thanking you.

Comment: Objective pronouns can't be modified by relative clauses. Demonstrative pronouns can.

Comment: @jlawler When we reduce the sentence to "I pity them" and "I pity those", both "those" and "them" are objective pronoun. Aren't they?

Comment: What are you asking? Whether they're grammatical?

Comment: @curiousdannii just to know the real reason why we can't say this.

Comment: Okay. I personally think it's questionably grammatical, but it's not as clearly okay as the first.

Comment: I have both in my dialect. The second strikes me as being characteristic of Northern British English (i'm from the North of England).

Comment: It's a question of register. Standard English today allows demonstrative pronouns, but not personal pronouns, to take a relative clause as modifier. But until quite recently *they who* and *them who* were both as grammatical as *those who*, and you can still find *them who* in non-standard varieties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jlawler's comment contains the direct answer to the question. Definite personal pronouns (I/me, you, he/him, she/her, it, we/us, they/them) cannot take a restrictive modifier. In other words, they cannot take a dependent that narrows the set of entities that they denote. This trait of personal pronouns underlies their use as test words for constituent structure. For example:

```
 (a)  The man with the hat knows the woman with the scarf.

 (b)  He knows her. 

 (c) *He with the hat knows her with the scarf.
```

Sentence (a) is the starting sentence. Sentence (b) shows proform substitution; the personal pronouns *he* and *her* have been substituted in for the noun phrases *the man with the hat* and *the woman with the scarf*. Based on the acceptability of sentence (b), one concludes that both *the man with the hat* and *the woman with the scarf* are constituents. Definite pronouns such as *he* and *her* (and *them*) take the place of constituents, in this case of complete noun phrases.

The unacceptability of sentence (c) reveals that the strings *the man* and *the woman* in (a) are not constituents. In other words, the definite personal pronouns *he* and *her* cannot take dependents (=modifiers), since they necessarily replace an entire noun phrase. This fact explains why *them who lost their money* in the question is bad English. The relative clause *who lost money* is a postdependent (=postmodifier), and as such it cannot modify *them* (because *them* as a definite personal pronoun cannot be modified).

The plural demonstrative pronouns (*these* and *those*) behave differently. They can take postdepndents (=postmodifiers, i.e. a modifier that follows them), e.g

```
 (d)  These with hats know those with scarves.
```

This is simply a trait of the plural demonstrative pronouns (*these* and *those*) -- there is no good explanation why plural demonstrative pronouns behave differently than definite personal pronouns; they simply do. Note that the plural demonstrative pronouns also behave differently than the singular demonstrative pronouns in this regard, e.g.

```
 (e)  *This with a hat knows that with a scarf.
```

Singular demonstrative pronouns (*this* and *that*) are behaving like the definite personal pronouns; they cannot take dependents.

The combination **plural demonstrative pronoun + restrictive relative clause** can actually be viewed as a particular construction in English and related languages. That is, it is a combination that occurs relatively frequently and has therefore been lexicalized. German has a very similar construction, e.g.

```
 (f) Diejenigen mit einem Hut kennen diejenigen mit einem Schal. 
     those      with  a   hat  know     those   with  a   scarf.
```

By acknowledging that one has a particular construction, one is in a sense admitting that there is no real grammatical "explanation" for the phenomenon. It simply exists.

Finally, note that there are certain apparent exceptions to the principles mentioned above. There are uses of personal pronouns that actually allow modification, e.g.

```
 (g) He who studies a lot gets a good grade.
```

In this example, the personal pronoun *he* is not referring directly to a specific entity, which means it is not definite; it is, rather, being used as an indefinite pronoun; it means 'the one, anyone', e.g. *Anyone who studies a lot gets a good grade*.

Comment: There is a modern short story by Saul Bellow: "Him with his foot in his mouth". Now that is colloquial English, isn't it?

Comment: There is another sentence I found "It was she who drank the blood from the baby". Here also "she" takes a modifier. Here "she" is no doubt a definite pronoun. So why it's here? Please explain.

Comment: Nominative personal pronouns can be modified by relative clauseas just like demonstrative pronouns; it's the objective personal pronouns that can't. _He who, she who, they who, you who_ are all grammatical, if archaic. _Him who, her who, them who,_ however, aren't.

Comment: Thanks @jlawler and Tim Osborne for your valuable contributions.

Comment: @jlawler But in Osborne's answer this sentence was marked as incorrect - ***He with the hat knows her with the scarf.*** But why, then?

Comment: @jlawler *Him who* etc. are the same as *he who* etc. in being "grammatical if archaic": cf. *Let him who is without sin cast the first stone*, and many other such examples. I see no difference between the nominative and objective pronouns in this regard.

Comment: @Man from India, the example "It was she who drank the blood from the baby" is an instance of clefting. I prefer a flat analysis of clefting, which means my preferred analysis takes "who drank the blood from the baby" as a dependent of the verb "was", not of the pronoun "she". Note that the object form of the pronoun also works: "It was her who drank the blood from the baby".

Comment: @Man from India, there is another type of exception to the general principle. If the relative clause is non-restrictive, it can modify a definite personal pronoun at times, e.g. "They asked me, who knew what was going on, to help", He, who was very clear about what he wanted, was courting Susan". Nonrestrictive relative clauses are set off by commas in orthography, and they tend to have a distinct intonation contour in prosody.

Comment: @TimOsborne I think there's a lot of variation in the acceptability of sentences like those in your last comment; to me they sound very borderline (though not quite ungrammatical).

Comment: @TimOsborne You mentioned that in the sentence - It is she who drank the blood from the baby - "who drank the blood from the baby" depends on the verb "was", not on the pronoun "she", and that's why it's an exception to the rule you mentioned in your answer. But how to determine the relative clause is dependent on what?

Comment: @TimOsborne Another favor I will ask. In your answer you have pretty much included the rule. Can you please include the exceptions as well?

Comment: @TimOsborne "It was her who drank blood from the baby" - is it a correct sentence? I think only correct form would be if we change "her" to "she".

Comment: @jlawler Consider this sentence - ***The action was performed by her who was the secretory of XYZ office***. In this sentence objective personal pronoun **her** takes a restrictive relative clause. So what is the basic rule? I request you also to write down some rules using examples, and their exceptions. As it stands no, I am getting confused.

Comment: _The action was performed by the person who was the secretary of XYZ,_ or, more likely, _The action was performed by the secretary of XYZ._ Why reach for an unsteady construction when there is a simple and clear way to say it? Unless one wishes to be unclear.

Comment: @jlawler I wrote this sentence only for the purpose of understanding the concept clearly. Please tell me why here the objective personal pronoun is getting modified. Or you can use any other examples where objective personal pronoun is getting modified by restrictive relative clause.

Comment: Um, I would say it was ungrammatical in American English. Indian English is, of course, a very different language.

Comment: @jlawler So the only rule for standard english is objective pesonal pronoun can't take a restrictive and non restrictive personal pronoun. Right?

Comment: Which standard English? The normal rule in American English is that either kind of personal pronoun can't take a relative clause. But there are a number of formal fixed phrases, like _He who hesitates is lost_. They mostly use nominative, so that sounds more familiar. But there should be no reason to modify a pronoun with a relative clause. Pronouns are very light, predefined, and meant to slip past fast; anything that needs a restrictive relative clause modifying it should be a noun.

Comment: That's a strange thing to say. Lots of languages have no problem with relative clauses that depend on pronouns.

Comment: Another striking example would be "what is it that makes you so sure?" "… It that…" is quite common, but seeing that there's a rule for this kind of stuff makes me doubt its grammaticality. The same goes for "those of them/you who..."

Comment: @jlawler your claim that in AE the sentence - ***The action was performed by her who was the secretory of XYZ office.*** - is wrong is making me more confused when I see this answer - http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/28880/3463

Answer (score 2):

"God helps them who help themselves" is a well-known proverb in English. Your second sentence ("I pity them who...") is correct English, though not perhaps the most usual way to say this. There is nothing wrong with "He with the hat knows her with the scarf" either. Both belong to an elevated (literary) style.

Comment: Hmmmm. My sense of the language disagrees with your claim; "he with the hat" is quite bad. Your sentence "God helps them who help themselves" is also not so good; I prefer "God helps those who help themselves".

Comment: How about this one: "Then let them which are in Iudea, flee to the mountaines, and let them which are in the midst of it, depart out, and let not them that are in the countreys, enter thereinto", Luke 21,21 KJV.

Comment: King James biblical English is not representative of how the language is used in our modern times; it is quite stilted.

Comment: I do not contest that "them who" and "them that" are not exactly modern colloquial English. I am protesting mainly against your contention that there is some logical underlying law that rules out these constructions. Language is not about logic but about usage. Until very recently the language of Shakespeare and the of KJV (both 17th century) were regarded as the supreme models of good English style.

Comment: I contest the implication of your comments, this implication being that the language allows anything at all. The notion that "them who" or "them that" are acceptable in the modern language is blind to how the vast majority of people speak English. Proform substitution as a test for constituent structure is widely employed in syntax textbooks. Would you like me to list some sources?